# How do I get non-italic words in a theorem environment?

Tags: theorems

I want some words in my theorem environment to not be italic. I know there are simple ways to get the entire theorem in roman, but I'm looking for an italic theorem with specified words in roman.

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newtheorem{mydef}{Definitie}[section]
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{LightGray}

\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}\begin{mydef}
I want \textrm{this} word to be non-italic.
\end{mydef}\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

But apparently `\textrm` is not the way to go because everything is still italic

Answer (score 54, accepted):

use

```
I want \textup{this} word to be non-italic.
```

Comment: This is the best answer to the question as posed. `\emph` is a semantic annotation to convey emphasis. It's only in certain document styles that it toggles between roman and italic. (One could argue that visual markup shouldn't be used in the end document at all, but that's a different issue altogether.)

Answer (score 31):

Use the `\emph` command to emphasize a word. Normally, this will italicize the word, but if you are already in italics mode, it will do the opposite.

Comment: As a bonus, putting math inside `\emph{}` within italics mode (e.g., in a theorem) also appears to correct the poor spacing that often occurs otherwise.